# Docker user write permissions issue

Tags: docker, container

I am just learning Docker. I have the following lines in my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stable

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    vim \
    ruby \
    rubygems \
    bundler \
    nodejs \
    build-essential

RUN adduser --disabled-login admin
RUN usermod -aG sudo admin
USER admin
RUN whoami
COPY sampleapp /app
RUN export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
RUN gem install rake
WORKDIR /app
RUN bundle install
```

When I run `docker build`, I get the following error in the output

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

How can I fix this error?

- Should I give access to these directories for admin
- Should I change the GEM_HOME to somewhere else instead ~/home?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do and build. In addition you should try to check which line exactly is causing the error (I'm not really familiar with Ruby but my guess would be the gem install line or the bundle install line. In addition you're copying your stuff to `/app` so why would you set your home to `$HOME`? Right now your user is probably missing the corresponding permissions. You might need to run `sudo gem ...` or `sudo bundle ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest is to look at the user permissions for the user executing your dockerfile and the permissions on the /var/lib/gems/... directories. Make sure your write and execute permissions are enough to run all of the commands in your dockerfile.

Secondly, since you are new to Docker, here is a link to resources on [Docker commands](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Docker+CLI+Commands) for additional information.